# how to update formset

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

i've created web blog with django 2.2 each post has multiple images , but when i try to update the post the images wont updated 
i use class based view

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #others

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images')
    media_files = models.FileField(upload_to=random_url)
```

and this my forms.py

```
class PostImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = [
            'media_files'
        ]
class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
           'title','description',#and others
        ]
```

my views.py

```
PostImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
Post,PostImage,form=PostImageForm,extra=1,can_delete=True,can_order=False
) 

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = 'posts/update_post.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['images'] = PostImageFormSet(self.request.POST or None,self.request.FILES,instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['images'] = PostImageFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data
    def form_valid(self,form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        images = context['images']
        with transaction.atomic():
            if form.is_valid() and images.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()
                images.instance = self.object
                images.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.username == post.user.username:
            return True
        return False
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('post:post-detail',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})
```

my templates

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{images.management_form }}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        {% for img in images %}
            <label>{{img.media_files.label}}</label>
              {{img.media_files}}
        {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">update</button>
    </form>
```

it only save the post form not images , it doesnt affect images form
thanks

Comment: Without properly testing your code, this line looks wrong to me,                 images.instance = self.object

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of writing:

```
images.instance = self.object
```

Please try this:

I noticed you are using the form is valid so it might be slightly different, but if you change it a bit it should work.

```
form = PostUpdateForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    images = cd.get('images')
```

Or using your current setup(not tested yet)

if form.is_valid() //Remove this part -> and images.is_valid():

```
   if form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        instance = self.object
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        images = cd.get('images')
        images.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ,and i got this error get_internal_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: please if you know another way let me know , i will appreciate

Comment: I just noticed your message

Comment: which line does it say that on?

Comment: the error related to something else , i solved , but still cant be updated

Comment: please check my update, also dont forget images.save()

Comment: still getting error : Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: images has no attribute save

Comment: does it work for you?if yes , please can you put the entire Update class

Comment: How did you go? I have been super busy, If you still having trouble I can help more over the weekend

Comment: if you can helped with this new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466783/update-method-in-createview-django-for-manytomany-field let me know please