# how to update ManyToManyField while an instance been created

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, signals

i want to to update field whenever an instance been created i tried `signals` but it seems complicate to `ManyToManyField`

```
class MobileCustomer(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    mobile = models.ManyToManyField(MobileStorage,through='SelectMobile')

class SelectMobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MobileCustomer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    imei = models.ManyToManyField(Imei)

class MobileStorage(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile_name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

i want to update active field in `Imei` model when `MobileCustomer` created !?
i tried this in my `CreateView form_valid`

```
imei = Imei.objects.filter(selectmobile__item=self.object).update(active=False)
print(imei)
```

and it printed 0 ?
how to make it work either using signals or update() whenever an instance created inside createview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to use `m2m_changed` signal look like this `def

```
def update_m2m(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
     Imei.objects.filter(pk__in=kwargs.get("pk_set")).update(active=False)
m2m_changed.connect(update_m2m,sender=SelectMobile.imei.through)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### lookup problem. mobile lookup to MobileStorage, then mobilecustomer lookup to MobileCustomer.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
  # self.object = None
  super().form_valid(form)
  # self.object = a instance of MobileCustomer
  imei = Imei.objects.filter(mobile__mobilecustomer=self.object).update(active=False)
  print(imei)
```

Comment: where we should put it ? inside MobileCustomer createView?

Comment: its a ManyToMany relationship sometimes we have more than one imei , so it cant update

Answer (score 1):

I think the relationship you are looking for is: `Imei > MobileStorage > SelectMobile > MobileCustomer`. You can try like this:

```
imei = Imei.objects.filter(mobile__selectmobile__item=self.object).update(active=False)
print(imei)
```

`post_save` signal example:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MobileCustomer)
def do_something(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        imei = Imei.objects.filter(mobile__selectmobile__item=instance).update(active=False)
    print(imei)
```

Comment: still doesnt work , the field wont be updated  , and print 0 , while the imei is not 0

Comment: its a ManyToMany relationship sometimes we have more than one imei , so it cant update

Answer (score 0):

Using .filter() will return a list. You want to use something like a .get() or the following get or 404 to get a single object.

```
imei = get_object_or_404(Imei, pk=imei_id)
imei.active = False
imei.save()
```

If you already have the object which is self.object you can use

```
imei = self.object
imei.active = False
imei.save()
```

Comment: thanks , but no ! this doesnt work , i want to update whenever MobileCustomer been created